# what is a small dependency of Pdf viewer?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm searching to find a small and useful dependency to view pdf in my android application. I have found AndroidPdfViewer and android-pdfview dependencies. But the first one size is too large (16 MB) and the second one is deprecated (it returns to 4 years ago).
can you please guide me?

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer
https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android Adds about 3MB to the app,Its a good port of Apache PDFBOX for Android. 
I have also worked with https://github.com/voghDev/PdfViewPager, not sure how much it adds to the apk size